# set text to left while other elements are centered - CSS - Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I thought what I was trying to do was pretty simple.
On the below image I want the description 'Print Flags' to be in the left of the box with the buttons centered in the right:
[image]

But this is as close as I have been able to get it.

Here is my code (currently):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/VERSION/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/VERSION/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css">


 <div class="col" style="position: relative; text-align: center; border-style: solid; border-width: thin">
                <div  style="position: absolute; left: 0px;  background-color: #ff8c00; font-weight: bold;">Print Flags
                </div>
                    <kendo-button name="printTrue" type="button" onclick="FlipAllPrintFlags(1)">All Print To True</kendo-button>
                    <kendo-button name="printFalse" type="button" onclick="FlipAllPrintFlags(2)"> All Print To False</kendo-button>
            </div>
```

Using a suggested answer it has gotten me closer, however, it has stopped filling the div vertically (although the code snippet looks correct)  I updated my code above to the latest:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/VERSION/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/VERSION/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="col" style="position: relative; text-align: center; border-style: solid; border-width: thin;">
    <div  style="position: absolute;left: 5px;top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)">
        Print Flags
    </div>
    <kendo-button name="printTrue" type="button" onclick="FlipAllPrintFlags(1)">All Print To True</kendo-button>
    <kendo-button name="printFalse" type="button" onclick="FlipAllPrintFlags(2)">All Print To False</kendo-button>
</div>
```

Comment: That certainly gets me closer.  I will update the question with what it is doing...

Comment: @JoeRuder I have updated my answer and this will fix the vertical alignment problem.

Comment: Thank you -- I added padding: 5px; and it looks perfect combined with your changes.